# brownie : File outside of allowed directories

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin, brownie

i'm following Patrick Collins tutorial to create NFTs and here is my problem:

i'm trying to import this:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

My brownie config is this :

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2

compiler:   
  solc:
    remappings:
      - ‘@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0’
      - ‘@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2’

dotenv: .env
```

my .env is this

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=Here i've put my private Key
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=  Here i've put my infura project ID
```

and i've intalled chainlink and openzeppelin with pip

my error is this :

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
^-------------------------------------------------------^
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Dealing with the same issue here. It looks like no folder structure other than a flat folder is recognized by the compiler. I have to os.chdir to even compile a simple contract with no imports.

Answer (score 0):

Please install openzeppiln with below command -

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

Now change the import statement to -

```
import "./node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```